# How to decode JSON in a .VBS Script

Tags: json, vbscript

I'm trying to receive JSON through a get request over `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` and then to parse that into a VBS dictionary.

I'm able to receive the response in what looks like the proper JSON format. However I am met with an error When I use [this VbsJson class's decode method](http://demon.tw/my-work/vbs-json.html) on the `responseText` of my request.

> Cannot convert variant type of (Dispatch) to Olestr

I'm an absolute newcomer to vbs and would like a simple way to get this data into a dictionary (better if I can also define the fields that I want to extract).

The code:

```
Sub Search(Sender)
  Dim Resp, Data
  Dim UrlToGet2
  UrlToGet2 = http://www.mywebsite.com/json
  Set Data = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  xHttp.Open "GET", UrlToGet2, False
  xHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"

  xHttp.Send

  If xHttp.Status <> 200 Then
    Set Resp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Resp.Add "success", "false"
    Resp.Add "error", "HTTP Error: " & xHttp.Status & " " & xHttp.StatusText
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Set Resp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim x, json
  Set json = New VbsJson
  Set x = json.Decode(xHttp.responseText)
  With Resp
    Dim a: a = x.Keys
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To x.Count -1
      .Add a(i), x(a(i))
    Next
  End With
  Set xHttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Post the code that isn't working. A guess is (as it's not a VBS error) that you are passing an object instead of a string.

Comment: @Noodles I posted the code

Comment: So I guess this is happening on the line that says `Set x = json.Decode(xHttp.responseText)` ? (please confirm). `responseText` is meant to return a string so I'm suprised at that error. When you have a lot going on in one line and you get an unexpected error, it's best to split it out. So first load responseText into a seperate variable, inspect it (with a `msgbox`), then use it in the `Decode` method. I guess you are using the class from here:  https://github.com/eklam/VbsJson. Don't you need to import the VBSJson.VBS somehow? I don't see it in your code.

Comment: Yes this is the line where it crashes. I've written the class in line with the rest of the code. When breaking the responseText up into separate variables, I now receive the error "object required" when I set an intermediary variable to the responseText.

Comment: What does the `xHttp.responseText` look like ?

Comment: So based on your comment, the issue is actually around getting the responseText out rather than anything to do with json at this stage